Netsuite PO PDF download
In the NetSuite UI, we can print the PDF for a PO.  How can we do the same thing programmatically, preferably using RESTful services (so external to NetSuite, from my application or via a shell script)?
I know how to find the PO using SuiteQL (I have a python script that does that already), but that is as far as I have gotten.  There are some rather close answers on StackOverflow, but they all reference RESTlets, which are not an option in my case.  If it is technically impossible, that is what I need to know.

RESTlets are how you implement a custom restful service in NetSuite. Why is one not an option?

Because RESTlets are local to NetSuite, and I would have to install a custom RESTlet on the customer's account.  Also, not that you are saying thism but strictly speaking you do not have to use RESTlets to do a custom restful service.  For instance, I don't use RESTlets for my Suiteql stuff, it is all purely from my server.  So long as my account and user has permission, I can do it.  I even have test code in POSTMAN to download, for instance, sales orders using https://.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder, and it works reasonably well.
